# Android:How to call a function when I click on push notification

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

```
void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    try {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm=GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        sendNotification();
        showPage();
    }
}
```

How to call showPage() when i click on push notification otherwise it should not call?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand please elaborate.

Comment: how u r setting the notification.?

Comment: The problem is when it is returned from sendNotification() it should call another function(in my showPage()) only when I click on notification otherwise it should not call.

Comment: while passing the intent put extra to the intent like put extra int 0, and in the activity if the intent has extras and intent data is 0 call that method

Comment: Ok I will try just tell me one thing who calls this onRecieve method and where to put extra in this intent, I am not able to find it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html see this example 
and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("tag", 1);
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

This will call your `DemoActivity`. You now have to get the intent and check if there are any `Extras` added.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getIntExtra("tag", 0) == 1) {
        showpage();
}
```

Comment: Suppose there are two classes MainActivity and Gcm. In GCM I have 3 functions ->showPage(),onReceive() sendNotification()// in sendNotification I added                                                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("tag", 1);                                                     but I am on GCM.java and i am calling showPage() on GCM.java and thats why it is showing intent.getExtra is null.

Comment: What do you mean with '3 functions'?

Comment: Call the GCM.class with your intent, what's your issue?

Comment: In GCM.java I have three methods onRecieve calls sendNotification and then receive it and then send call showPage(). My issue is I need to call showPage() only whenever the user clicks on push notification.

Comment: `PendingIntent` is exactly what you want.

Comment: What is GCM, activity or anything else. If it is activity you should replace MainAactivity.class with GCM.class .

Comment: @Leandros-How to use PendingIntent could you please elaborate